# mmap error : segmentation fault/invalid pointer error

Tags: c++, mmap

I am new to mmap and still learning it . Based on my understanding i have created class for mmap which will be used to map a file in memory . The entire class is working fine but problem is coming when destructor is called ..the problem is segmentation fault or invalid pointer error is coming at the end of main function ...I have posted code of my class and main function which is using that class ...

Map.h

```
class MapData   
{
     public :
            MapData();
            ~MapData();
            MapData(char []);
            bool OPEN();    
            void fnClose();
            long fnGetSize();
            char * fnGetFileRef();
            char * ReadNextData(int );

private :
            char * ptrRecord;
            char  ptrFileNm[250+1];
            int fd;
            struct stat sbuf;
            bool bSuccess;
            long sTotalSize;
            char acData[2000+1];
            long lCurrRead;

};
```

MapData.cpp

```
MapData::MapData()
{

}

MapData::~MapData()
{
   printf("Inside MADATA Destructor \n ");
}

MapData::MapData(char acInput[])
{
    strcpy(ptrFileNm,acInput);
    sTotalSize=0;
    lCurrRead=0;
    bSuccess=false;
}

bool MapData::OPEN()
{

    // if failed return false flg
    if ((fd = open(ptrFileNm, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
    return bSuccess;
    }

    if (stat(ptrFileNm, &sbuf) == -1) {
       return bSuccess;
    }

    // copy in local variable
    sTotalSize = sbuf.st_size;

    ptrRecord = (char * )mmap( (caddr_t)0, sTotalSize, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0) ;

    if (ptrRecord == (char *)(caddr_t)(-1) ) {
       perror("Fail to Map Data ");
       return bSuccess;
    }
    else
    {
       printf("Successfully Map Data***[%ld] \n",sTotalSize);
       bSuccess=true;
    }

    return bSuccess;
}

char * MapData::fnGetFileRef()
{
    return ptrRecord;
}

char * MapData::ReadNextData(int iX)
{
    if((lCurrRead+iX)<sTotalSize)
    {
        memset(acData,0x00,sizeof(acData));
        strncpy(acData,ptrRecord+lCurrRead,iX);
        acData[iX+1]='\0';
        lCurrRead+=iX;
    }else{
        strcpy(acData,"ZZZ");
    }
    return acData;
}

long MapData::fnGetSize()
{
    return sTotalSize;
}

void MapData::fnClose()
{
     // Don't forget to free the mmapped memory
     if(munmap(ptrRecord, sTotalSize) == -1)
     {
         close(fd);
         perror("Error un-mmapping the file");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
     // Un-mmaping doesn't close the file, so we still need to do that.
     close(fd);
     printf("CLOSED SUCCESSFULLY \n ");
}
```

Main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    char acFileNm[500+1];
    MEMSET(acFileNm);           // clean the variable
    // file name to be read 
    strcpy(acFileNm,"ABDFILE.txt");

    long lProcCnt=0;                    // no of byte read by program
    char acLine[MAX_LINE_LENGTH+1]; // hold current read line
    bool bFlag=true;        // main flag 

    DEBUG_PRINT("File to be processed:%s \n",acFileNm);

    // create object of mmap
    MapData * pt1 = NULL;
    pt1 = new MapData(acFileNm);

    if(!pt1)
    {
        cout<<"Error creating object so quit ..."<<endl;
        return 0 ;
    }

    auto_ptr<MapData> ptrMap( pt1 );                    // pass ownership to auto deletor to delete memory


    DEBUG_PRINT("STEP1:%s \n","OBJECT CREATION FOR FILE MAPPED IN MEMORY");


    // try to open the file 
    if(ptrMap->OPEN())
    {
            // on success..get pointer to first char of file
            char * ptrData = ptrMap->fnGetFileRef();
            long lCompSize=ptrMap->fnGetSize();     // total no of bytes = fiexed line size * no of row + (no of row * EOL)


            short int iEOL=0;

            // logic to identify file generated on ewhich OS
            if( (*(ptrData+MAX_LINE_LENGTH) == '\r') && (*(ptrData+MAX_LINE_LENGTH+1) == '\n'))
            {
                    // DOS format CRLF
                    iEOL = 2;
            }else if(*(ptrData+MAX_LINE_LENGTH) == '\n'){
                    // Unix format LF
                    iEOL = 1;
            }

            DEBUG_PRINT("STEP2: SIZEOFFILE%ld FILESYSTEM FORMAT:%d \n",lCompSize,iEOL);


            // here read till it reaches maximum limit of file
            while(lProcCnt<lCompSize)
            {
                    //DEBUG_PRINT("PROC COUNTER[%ld] MAX_COUNTER[%ld] \n",lProcCnt,lCompSize);

                    lProcCnt+=MAX_LINE_LENGTH+iEOL;             // increement no of bytes read at initial

                    MEMSET(acLine);
                    strncpy(acLine,ptrData+lProcCnt,MAX_LINE_LENGTH);       // read line
                    acLine[MAX_LINE_LENGTH+1]='\0';

                    // process the line  :function is called here to process the line
            }

    }else{
            DEBUG_PRINT("MAP DATA FAILED OF FILE[%s] \n",acFileNm);
            bFlag=false;
    }

    // at the end check if all the controls are matched 
    if(bFlag)
    DEBUG_PRINT("END OF FILE PROCESSING SUCCESS \n");
    else        
    DEBUG_PRINT("END OF FILE PROCESSING FAILED \n");


    // close the memory map
    ptrMap->fnClose();

    MapData * ptr5 = ptrMap.release();      // release the ownership 

    delete ptr5;   **// segmentation fault comes here ...**
}
```

Please suggest me where i am going wrong since gdb is also not helping ...detailed explanation will be good for me to understand ...

```
Stacktrace generated by gdb:

*** glibc detected *** DemoMap: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0804c000 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0x9bbc81]
/lib/libc.so.6[0x9be562]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x22)[0x544552]
DemoMap[0x80491e6]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0x961d36]
DemoMap[0x8048d91]
======= Memory map: ========
00110000-00111000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
0044c000-00469000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1237       /lib/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
00469000-0046a000 rw-p 0001d000 08:03 1237       /lib/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
00495000-00576000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 132841     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
00576000-0057a000 r--p 000e0000 08:02 132841     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
0057a000-0057c000 rw-p 000e4000 08:02 132841     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
0057c000-00582000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00929000-00947000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1065       /lib/ld-2.12.so
00947000-00948000 r--p 0001d000 08:03 1065       /lib/ld-2.12.so
00948000-00949000 rw-p 0001e000 08:03 1065       /lib/ld-2.12.so
0094b000-00adb000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1067       /lib/libc-2.12.so
00adb000-00adc000 ---p 00190000 08:03 1067       /lib/libc-2.12.so
00adc000-00ade000 r--p 00190000 08:03 1067       /lib/libc-2.12.so
00ade000-00adf000 rw-p 00192000 08:03 1067       /lib/libc-2.12.so
00adf000-00ae2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00b29000-00b51000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1211       /lib/libm-2.12.so
00b51000-00b52000 r--p 00027000 08:03 1211       /lib/libm-2.12.so
00b52000-00b53000 rw-p 00028000 08:03 1211       /lib/libm-2.12.so
08048000-0804b000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 2883976    DemoMap
0804b000-0804c000 rw-p 00002000 08:08 2883976    DemoMap
0804c000-0806d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7e00000-b7e21000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7e21000-b7f00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7f9b000-b7fe5000 r--s 00000000 08:08 4326707    ABCDEF.TXT
b7fe5000-b7fe8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7ffd000-b8000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bffeb000-c0000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

Comment: Edited...This class i am going to use for file processing by mapping the file in memory for faster access ...

Comment: Please consider adding debugging outputs (like `printf`s) to boil it down to a more specific section of the code, this may help identify the problem. How should the destructor be the problem if all that is done there is `printf("Inside MADATA Destructor \n ");`?

Comment: I tried debugging in each possible way using gdb ...the program get executed fine but on delete call of Mmap pointer the destructor get called and program stops..i am posting here stack trace generated by gdb........

Comment: The most basic C++ programming guideline violated:
The function pair mmap/munmap has to be put into the constructor/destructor of a class in order to exploit RAII. Same for open/close. Please use std::string for strings. And AVOID strcpy like the plague. Your class does not make sense, as it represents only a filename when created with the matching constructor and when using the default constructor it represents nothing. There is no need for this. To represent a filename a std::string is fully sufficient. To represent nothing you can use void.

Comment: The methods open/close exported by your class exhibit multi-step-initialization -- something which is out of date since 20 years.

Answer (score -1):

may be here.

```
char  ptrFileNm[250+1];
char acFileNm[500+1];

MapData::MapData(char acInput[])
{
    strcpy(ptrFileNm,acInput);//segmentation fault 
    sTotalSize=0;
    lCurrRead=0;
    bSuccess=false;
}
```

Comment: i have checked there is no problem with filename variable ... problem is while executing destructor of Mmap ....